# Prefix namespace in RDF

Tags: resources, rdf, jena, prefix

I have this RDF statement (turtle format):

```
@prefix cd:      <http://mai.com/contactwrapper/0.1#> .

<http://mai.com/contactwrapper/0.1#malzaa@m.com>
      cd:Belongs_To "1"^^xmls:string ;
      cd:Email_Address "malzaa@m.com"^^xmls:string ;
      cd:Email_Type "WORK"^^xmls:string .
```

As you can see, the prefix worked with the properties (Belongs_To, Email_Address, and Email_Type) but didn't work with the name of the resource (malzaa@m.com). Because "http://mai.com/contactwrapper/0.1#" should be replaced by cd.

Could anyone please explain whats wrong with that ??

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The abbreviated form is often called a *QName* (which stands for "qualified name"). The reason `cd:malazaam@m.com` does not work as a QName are the `@` and the `.` char in the part behind the `:`. Turtle syntax does not allow these characters in a QName, which is why the full URI is used instead.

See the [Turtle grammar](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/#nameChar) for an overview of what characters are allowed in a QName.

As an aside: your Turtle fragment does not declare the `xmls:` namespace either (which you use for your literal datatypes), so it will fail to parse.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. The xmls is already defined but not shown in the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

As Jeen says "@" is not allowed in a prefixed name in Turtle, despite prefixed name being broader than QNames.

In RDF 1.1, the Turtle language is being formally standardized. "@" is not legal in the local part of prefixed names,  but "\@" is.

The latest grammar is: http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-grammar-grammar

There are many parers that accept the traditional Turtle.  Jena writers are conservative - they output legal RDF in a way to maximise the chances of being readable by another parser.  Writing in full <..> form or using a prefixed name does not change the URI being written, only it's surface appearance.